# Marionette get dynamic segement + query params

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a marionette router -

```
var Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        'user/:id/waiting?*queryParam': 'waiting',
        '*notFound': 'notFound'
    }
});
```

And in my `routerController` I am trying to access the dynamic segment "id" along with the queryParam passed.

```
var RouterController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    waiting: function(id) {
        console.log(id);
       // How to access "queryParam" over here ?

    }
});
```

How can I access "*queryParam" too in my controller via backbone/marionette way ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to receive the `splats` as second argument

```
var RouterController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    waiting: function(id, queryParam) {
        console.log(id);
       // How to access "queryParam" over here ?

    }
});
```

Comment: you mean as "function(id, splats)" ?

Comment: No, `splats` is a standard term used for expression `*queryParam`. The name of the variable can be anything, you want.